# Build new column from a function in a pandas Dataframe using values from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm a new to pandas DataFrame, and I'm having a bit of struggle as I can't figure how to access a particular cell to make calculation to fill a new cell.

I'd like to use apply to call a external function with data from a cell at row - 1.

I did that, but outputing everything in a simple array, but i'm pretty sure there is a better way to do it:

I build my dataFrame from a csv with the following index:

```
DateIndex = pd.date_range(start="2005-1-1", end="2017-1-1", freq=BDay())
```

I'm positive my dataframe is ok, as per the extract below:

```
2005-01-03    0.005742
2005-01-04    0.003765
2005-01-05   -0.005536
2005-01-06    0.001500
2005-01-07    0.007471
2005-01-10    0.002108
2005-01-11   -0.003195
2005-01-12   -0.003076
2005-01-13    0.005416
2005-01-14    0.003090
```

So, I would like to add 100 to the first entry, and for the other ones, add one and then multiply it by the previous entry.

I was able to do so in an array:

```
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
    if i == 0:
        listV = [df.iloc[i] + 100]
    else:
        listV.append(listV[i-1] * (1 + df.iloc[i]))
```

is there a way to do this and put the result directly in a new column of the data frame ?

Thanks a lot,
Regards,
Julien

Comment: Just do `df['new column name'] = listV`. You need to remove the square brackets in your if statement  otherwise it will turn the value into a list. The line should also be inside of an append statement as you had under your else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***initialization***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        col=[ 0.005742,  0.003765, -0.005536,  0.0015  ,  0.007471,
              0.002108, -0.003195, -0.003076,  0.005416,  0.00309 ]
    ), pd.to_datetime([
            '2005-01-03', '2005-01-04', '2005-01-05', '2005-01-06', '2005-01-07', 
            '2005-01-10', '2005-01-11', '2005-01-12', '2005-01-13', '2005-01-14'])
    )

print(df)

                 col
2005-01-03  0.005742
2005-01-04  0.003765
2005-01-05 -0.005536
2005-01-06  0.001500
2005-01-07  0.007471
2005-01-10  0.002108
2005-01-11 -0.003195
2005-01-12 -0.003076
2005-01-13  0.005416
2005-01-14  0.003090
```

---

***comments***
This looks to be a series of returns.  By adding `100` to the first observation, you are marginalizing that first return making it `.57` **basis points** as opposed to `.57` **percent**

I believe what you want to do is add to add one to everything, then take the cumulative product, then multiply by 100.

This would show the ***cumulative growth of 100*** which is what I believe you are after.

```
df.add(1).cumprod().mul(100)

                   col
2005-01-03  100.574200
2005-01-04  100.952862
2005-01-05  100.393987
2005-01-06  100.544578
2005-01-07  101.295746
2005-01-10  101.509278
2005-01-11  101.184956
2005-01-12  100.873711
2005-01-13  101.420043
2005-01-14  101.733431
```

---

```
df.add(1).cumprod().mul(100).plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Here's where the domain knowledge comes into play ;-)

Comment: Brilliant. That's exactly that ! I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way to achieve the same thing:

```
col_copy = df.col.copy()   # generate a copy to isolate the series completely
col_copy.iloc[0] += 100    # Increment first row by 100
col_copy.iloc[1:] += 1     # Increment 1 to rest

df.assign(new_col=col_copy.cumprod()) # compute cumulative product and assign to new column
```

yields:

[image]

***Data:***

Consider a `DF` with a single column `'Col'` as prepared:

```
txt = StringIO(
"""
2005-01-03    0.005742
2005-01-04    0.003765
2005-01-05   -0.005536
2005-01-06    0.001500
2005-01-07    0.007471
2005-01-10    0.002108
2005-01-11   -0.003195
2005-01-12   -0.003076
2005-01-13    0.005416
2005-01-14    0.003090
""")

df = pd.read_csv(txt, delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=True, header=None, 
                 index_col=['date'], names=['date', 'col'])
df.index.name = None
df
```

[image]